# Using the geolocation API to set a form input

Tags: javascript, forms, geolocation, set

I'm kind of a javascript noob, and I'm trying to use the new geolocation API in Firefox 3.5 to get an estimation of the user's coordinates and put that into a text box in a form. What I have doesn't seem to be working; it seems like the boxes are filled before the location is actually retreived. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lati =0;
        var longi =0;
        function getPosition(position) 
        {
            lati = position.coords.latitude;
            longi = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        function writeLati(form)
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation) { 
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
                lati = position.coords.latitude;
                longi = position.coords.longitude;
                form.latitude.value = lati;
                form.longitude.value = longi;
            } else {
                form.latitude.value = "3";
                form.longitude.value = "5";
                document.write("Your shitty browser can't do geolocation. Get Firefox 3.5.");
            }

        }



    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="writeLati(locform)">



    <form name="locform" action="submit.php" method="post" >
    Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude" value=""/>
    Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude" value="" />
    Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" checked="checked" /> Female
    <input type="submit"  />
    </form> 


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The form fields are getting filled early because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous.  You want to fill the form fields in the callback function (at which point `position` will actually be filled with the data), something more like this:

```
function getPosition(position) 
{
    lati = position.coords.latitude;
    longi = position.coords.longitude;
    form.latitude.value = lati;
    form.longitude.value = longi;
}
```

Of course, you should add some error handling because the existence of `navigator.geolocation` isn't a guarantee that the location will be available.  (Also, you should make it clear to users that you're not storing the location until the form is submitted -- a lot of people may be scared off by a form that fills in one's location automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question I recently ran-up against a similar issue.  Geotext does on the fly geo-location text replacement anywhere you can drop a class tag.  For example:

```
<input name="city" class="geotext[city]" />
<input name="state" class="geotext[state]" />
<input name="zip" class="geotext[zip]" />
```

Or:

```
Hello, how is sunny <span class="geotext[city,state,country]"></span>?
```

https://github.com/Frizzled/geotext

Answer (score 0):

this is not very practical - here is a javascript solution that is cross-browser and does exactly what you want to do, using 3rd party apis from yahoo etc.

http://icant.co.uk/geofill/index.php?demo=suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Native Geolocation is a cool new feature of FF3.5, but for now a cross browser solution is to use the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding)

This has given me reasonable results when I've used it but be aware that the accuracy will vary quite a lot be region, if your doing this it's nice to give your users a map so that they can refine the automatically generated position.